# sqlite3 when disk storage reached

Tags: database, sqlite, filesystems, persistence

I have a 2M bytes storage to store some logs in our embedded device (linux base). As the size is very limited, we have to implement some approach to handle the case that max size is reached. One option is circular buffer with mmap for persistence. The other option we are thinking is to use sqlite3 (when max size is reached, delete oldest entries, insert new ones).

However, as far as I understand, sqlite3 uses pages (limit 4096K or configurable). My questions are:

1. how to calculate disk usage from sqlite3? besides the database file size, what is also needed to count here?
2. what happens when 2M is reached? is there any particular info or error I could check to delete oldest entries?
3. is it a good approach (performance wise, data segmentation wise) to delete entries, then insert new ones?

Any suggestions or feedbacks are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to calculated the disk usage; you have to monitor the file. Besides the actual database file, there is also the rollback journal, whose size corresponds to the amount of changed data in a transaction.

When the disk is full, you get an error code of SQLITE_FULL (or maybe SQLITE_IOERR_WRITE, depending on the OS).

You can limit the database size with [PRAGMA max_page_count](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_max_page_count).

Deleted rows result in more free space in that particular database page. (This never changed the file size, unless you run [VACUUM](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html).)
When inserting new rows at the other end of the table, the space can get reused only when the entire page was freed because all its rows were deleted.
So you should try to delete rows in large chunks, if possible.

Comment: thanks.CL. I made a loop to insert and delete the entries multiple times (each is done by sqlite_exec convenience function over 2M), i expect the file size to grow. however, it remains the same. This is a bit contradictory if the free space is only taken back by VACCUM. Also where is the rollback journal file? I only find the database file in the directory.

Comment: Free space *can* be reused by other rows; VACUUM affects the file size. With the default [setting](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode), the rollback journal is deleted after each transaction.

Comment: yeah, rollback journal is only temporary file. I got it now. I also tried to insert, e.g. 2M rows, which results in e.g., size 82066432 bytes database file, Then i delete all these rows. the file size does not shrink.